# celery beat instantly stopping with resource error

Tags: celery

The logs of celery beat is like this where the last line just stopped and not continuing and recovering anymore.

```
[2018-08-20 11:20:59,002: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task check result delays every 10sec (notify_delay)
[2018-08-20 11:21:00,000: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task load abnormal schedules (load_abnormal_schedules)
[2018-08-20 11:21:00,004: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task check close schedule every 5sec (close_schedule)
[2018-08-20 11:21:05,000: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task check close schedule every 5sec (close_schedule)
[2018-08-20 11:21:10,000: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task check close schedule every 5sec (close_schedule)
[2018-08-20 11:21:14,002: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task check result delays every 10sec (notify_delay)
[2018-08-20 11:21:15,000: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task load abnormal schedules (load_abnormal_schedules)
[2018-08-20 11:21:15,003: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task check close schedule every 5sec (close_schedule)
[2018-08-20 11:21:20,000: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task check close schedule every 5sec (close_schedule)
[2018-08-20 11:21:25,000: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task check close schedule every 5sec (close_schedule)
[2018-08-20 11:21:29,003: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task check result delays every 10sec (notify_delay)
```

It is run inside a docker container. When I checked via top it shows a high CPU percentage

```
120549 root      20   0  356016 150144  16388 S  23.4  1.0   3:36.33 celery
```

Then when I ssh inside container and try to the celery beat command. The error below initially returned

```
root@4a298cc9c6e2:/usr/src/app# celery -A ghost beat -l info --pidfile=
celery beat v4.2.0 (windowlicker) is starting.

__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2018-08-20 11:32:51
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://ghost:**@ghost-rabbitmq:5672/ghost
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
[2018-08-20 11:32:51,526: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2018-08-20 11:32:51,535: ERROR/MainProcess] Removing corrupted schedule file 'celerybeat-schedule': error(11, 'Resource temporarily unavailable')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: 'scheduler'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 476, in setup_schedule
    self._store = self._open_schedule()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 466, in _open_schedule
    return self.persistence.open(self.schedule_filename, writeback=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/shelve.py", line 243, in open
    return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/shelve.py", line 227, in __init__
    Shelf.__init__(self, dbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dbm/__init__.py", line 94, in open
    return mod.open(file, flag, mode)
_gdbm.error: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Take note that I'm only using pure celery and not django-celery-beat

Answer (score 3):

My dear friend, when you every up your docker container, celery wants create celerybeat.pid file and If exist django raises error about this. So you should add these command for delete current celerybeat.pid file on your Dockerfile like this:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /code/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/code/entrypoint.sh"]
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
```

And you should create a entrypoint.sh file like below:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -rf /code/badpanty/*.pid
exec "$@"
```

I hope it's helpful.